# How to catch async exceptions with the safe-exceptions library?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, exception, thread-exceptions

I'm trying to dive into building concurrent and robust code with Haskell, and it was recommended that I use the [safe-exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions) and [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) libraries. However, I'm having a hard time understanding how to handle non-fatal errors thrown within an `async` action.

For instance, if there is a simple loop that is checking a network resource every *n* seconds, it would make sense to stop this using the `cancel` function which would cause an `AsyncCancelled` exception to be thrown within the seperate thread. Of course, there would also be the possibility that an `IOError` would be thrown from within the thread due to the network going down or some other problem. Depending on the type of exception and the data it contains, I would want to control whether the seperate thread ignores the exception, performs some action, stops, or raises the exception in the main thread.

With the safe-exceptions library, the only functions that are able to do this are `catchAsync` and others like it, which are labelled as dangerous in the documentation. Other than that, there is `waitCatch` in the async library, but the `fromException` function always returns `Nothing` when I try to extract an `IOError`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent hiding (throwTo)
import Control.Exception.Safe 
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.IO.Error hiding (catchIOError)

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    putStrLn "Press any key to continue..."
    a <- async runLoop
    async $ hWaitForInput stdin (-1) *> 
                throwTo (asyncThreadId a) (userError "error")
    waitCatch a >>= either handler nothing
  where
    printThenWait i = putStr (show i ++ " ") *> threadDelay 1000000
    runLoop = sequence_ $ printThenWait <$> [1..]
    nothing _ = pure ()
    handler e
        | Just (e' :: IOError)       <- fromException e = 
              putStrLn "It's an IOError!"
        | (Nothing :: Maybe IOError) <- fromException e = 
              putStrLn "We got Nothing!"
```

I'm a bit confused about the danger of recovering from async exceptions, especially when standard functions such as `cancel` cause them to be thrown, and I don't know what the recommended way to handle them would be when using these two libraries. Is this an instance where `catchAsync` *would* be recommended, or is there another way to handle these types of situations that I haven't discovered?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `Control.Exception.Safe.throwTo` [wraps](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.0/docs/Control-Exception-Safe.html#v:throwTo) synchronous exceptions into `AsyncExceptionWrapper`, and `IOError` **is** synchronous. (I have no idea why this wrapping is necessary, you should never throw synchronous exceptions asynchronously anyway.)

To make your code work, you should either catch `AsyncExceptionWrapper` or use `Control.Exception.throwTo`. But actually I don't compitely understand what you are trying to do, most likely you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: "you should never throw synchronous exceptions asynchronously anyway" indeed one shouldn't but, since it is possible, the wrapper seems like a good idea.

Comment: @danidiaz I'd prefer if it just fails immediately, it is less confusing.